# How to avoid overflow of inner div when resize the outer div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

`innerMain` gets resized automatically when I resize the outer div(`main`). I want both `header` and `footer` to remain at top and bottom of the `main` div. Both should be block elements – display=block – and only resize the `innerMain` when `main` change. My current solution is causing an overflow at the bottom. Can someone help me to fit all inner divs inside the outer div and avoid overflow?

I can't use the resize option of jQuery UI Resizable as I don't know the Dom element of inner div when I draw the outer div. (Final Dom structure is not available). Calculating any pixel sizes also not a solution for me.

jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/gHLgt/16/

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues here that can be resolved by adding / editing as follows:

```
.main { position: relative; }
.footer { position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
```

Then apply your jquery to the inner div instead of the outer wrapper:

```
$(".innerMain").resizable();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gHLgt/18/